"Insufficient data for an image" opening PDF created with Genexus
I have a report pdf created with Genexus17U10. I can open it with browsers, but when I try to open it with Adobe reader I get a white sheet and the message "Insufficient data for an image"
There are several posts about this, but none about Genexus and other prints in the same project work. What can cause this problem?

I found the problem, the image I used as the background of the PDF was too large. By reducing it the PDF is created correctly
